# How to count exact match of certain patterns in a text file using linux shell command?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find the count of certain pattern in a text file which contains lot of mixed patterns also using linux shell command.

I have a text file which contains below patterns,

```
[--------------]

[+--------------+]

[+----------+------------+--------------------+]

[+---------------------+---------------------+]
```

How to find exact count of only first pattern `[--------------]`?

Note: Don't include square bracket as a pattern. Only special character inside square bracket is a pattern.

Comment: For the above input text, what's your expected output?

Comment: Can there be more than one pattern per line? What are the patterns separated by? Is the `+` literal, or does it represent something else?

Comment: Please show a few representative lines of your actual data. And the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

**cat ./file | sed -e 's/\]/\]\n/' |grep "\[--------------\]" -c**

cat reads file
sed replace ] with ]\n  
grep searches every line for your expression and prints the number of lines -c